# pm2 restarts again and again

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean, pm2

I have my NodeJs server hosted on DigitalOcean.The server worked well for few days after which it stopped due to pm2 starting again and again.

This is a screenshot of my logs after starting it with pm2 start app.js
[image]

However, if I simply start my server using node app.js it works fine.

[image]

My code for listening on server is
[image]

I have not found any suitable answer for this problem.If more description to this problem is required then let me know.

Comment: I believe, `pm2` doesn't restart, it's your app that crashes. Try to look more content of logs, you may find crashing point of app.

Comment: There might be some memory leak because of which pm2 restarting server again and again . Please check your logs

Comment: check the error log ./pm2/

Comment: error log ./pm2/ is empty but the server starts by simply node app.js,if there are errors in the code then it would have shown on to the console

Comment: how to detect memory leak as I am new to node

Answer (score 0):

This mainly happens when your server does not kill previously running processes.These processes keep on running and they consume whole memory causing memory leak.

Process killing can be done using following code

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function handleSigterm() {
    server.close();});
```

this will kill all the previous running process

Comment: Where does the `process.` come from?